# How to authenticate either by email_id or contact_number in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want use a text field through which either contact_number or email_id can be passed as username and should authenticate

here is is what i have tried, but unable to authenticate

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select email_id as username,password,enabled from users where (email_id = ? or contact_number = ?)")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select email_id as username,'USER_ROLE' from users where (email_id = ? or contact_number = ?)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/signUp").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saveUserCompany").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
              .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
              .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll();
    }
```

**and my login page jsp**

```
           <form method="post" th:action="@{/login}" name="f">
             <fieldset>
                <%-- <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
                     Invalid username and password.
                 </div>
                 <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
                     You have been logged out. 
                 </div> --%>
                 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                 <div class="margin-top-10  form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="margin-top-10 form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                 </div>   
                 <div class="margin-top-10 form-actions form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <a class="register-link">Register</a>
                 </div>
                 </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: You cannot as the `usersByUsernameQuery` takes only a single argument not 2... You would have to implement your own `UserDetailsService` for that.

Comment: And then in that, you can check for multiple fields in parallel. I have my own implementation of it. If you want, let me know. you just have to call the userDetailsService instead of the SQL code that you have.

Comment: Yes @WeareBorg can you please post it for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the stuff you would require :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;

    public LoginServiceImpl() {
    }
    @Override
// below you can pass as username also. And the the dao method will be responsible to search phonenumber, emailid, birthdate, blood group, DNA encoding, depending how sophisticated your database search is. 
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
        if (person == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");
        }
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Above class requires an helper class :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity) {
        String username = userEntity.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        boolean enabled = userEntity.isEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
// I am manually assigniing role below as we dont have complex role management. 
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }
}
```

If any doubts, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how to call it from security config instead of SQL code

Comment: Cool, can you edit your main post to show how you modified the code. I am interested in knowing that. Also, if you accepted my answer, can you please click on the 'UP' arrow kind of thing where my answer starts. Thanks.